# How do i use regular expression for path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a path where some part is fixed and some can vary. 
Example "\myhome\tabke\jkl" is fixed. 
The ending part can be variable example 
"\myhome\tabke\jkl\mysum.txt" or "\myhome\tabke\jkl\groupdata\grsum.qpi"

How should i use regular expression using @pattern

Comment: How should you use a regular expression to do what?

Comment: What is your actual question?